# MySQL Flush hosts not doing its job. Any workaround?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, host

I am having a nightmare with mysql server.
I am unable to log in remotely after following numerous suggestions, I have a webpage that is supposed to log to a remote database to query it, but I always get access denied.
After several attempts, I got the host blocked error by mysql server:

Host 'ip address' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

I have tried flushing the host in the mysql console and through the command line, restarted the mysql service, changed the max_connect_errors and max_connections to 1000 and I am still getting the error above.

I have read countless threads about this, and they all seem to recommend what I have done. Basically flushing the hosts is not working although I get no error when I do it! Any help would be appreciated.

Server version: 5.5.49 on Ubuntu 14.04

**UPDATE:**
 I added:

```
skip-name-resolve
skip-host-cache
```

into my my.cf and the error is still there, what gives? if the block is due to the host_cache table data, which is now skipped?

Comment: Flush hosts won't fix the access denied issue. You've got either the wrong username, the wrong password, *or* the username needs to be set up to permit the IP address of the server making the SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The username and password work perfectly when I log through phpmyadmin. The username is created with localhost and the wildcard % with all privileges.

Comment: Turn on the error log and see what it says. Something like `121227  8:44:21 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` should be in there. https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/

Comment: That is the error I was getting before I got the blocked host error. My first issue to solve is unblock the host so I can figure out why the authentication is not getting validated.

Comment: Are you sure you're running `mysqladmin flush-hosts` against the right database server?

Comment: Positive. I just checked all the variables too. It makes no sense. What is doing my head in is if go to the server's phpmyadmin I log in successfully.

Comment: So what was the solution? This was 2 months ago.